# datetime VS timestamp performance

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

i have a query.this  should fetch records created 2 months ago. mysql table type is Innodb.
which type do i use for date (time). Datetime or Timestamp int(11) or Timestamp for better performance.
records is about 50000-100000.

```
....
    $monthsback = 2;
    $date = strtotime("-$monthsback months",time());
    $date =date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $date );  // if i use Datetime
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
    $recorddate=$result['date'];//fetched from mysql
    if ($recorddate>$monthsback)
    {
    echo "....";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "....";
    }
    }
...
```

Comment: It doesn't matter at all. Use the type that's right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're only dealing with a hundred thousand records?

Then this qualifies as a *micro-optimization*.

Pick the column type that *best fits* the data.  `DATETIME` is going to end up being the best, most flexible column type for storing date and time information, because that's what it's designed to do.

Change this *only* when you can *prove* that another method is faster.  Do this by **[benchmarking and profiling your code](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)** to find *real* bottlenecks.

Comment: Would have sworn this post said 5000000-10000000 when I first looked at it. Agreed

Comment: the way i compare dates (line 3,4,8) is true?    is there any better code to do this?

Comment: 5000000-10000000 if i have  a  user table for a small country! :)

Comment: @a.v, other than needing to use `strtotime` on the `DATETIME` column that comes back from the database, your code would work for comparison.  I'd personally use a PHP [DateTime](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [`diff`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method, new in PHP 5.3.